# ¿Como ejecutar un datepicker en un input que obtuve con ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo una página Web donde en ciertas partes cargo contenido con `ajax`, en una de estas partes, cargo un formulario en el cual al tener el foco un `input`, se abre un `datepicker`.
E
l problema es que al traerlo con `ajax` no se abre este `plugin`, y si no lo cargo con `ajax`, si se abre.

para traer el formulario es algo similar a esto.

```
function traigo_form()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            data:{enviado: true}   
            type: "POST",
            url: "localhost/miproyecto/traer_form.php",
            success: function (data)
            {
                $('#formulario').html(data);             
            }
        });

  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes instanciar de nuevo el ambito de datepicker en el componente.

Luego de

> $('#formulario').html(data);

Inicializa el componente

> $('#tucampo').datepicker();

En caso contrario pega el código que tienes en traer_form.php para evaluarle.